# Remove space when post title is blank

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-title

I want my custom post type title leave no spaces when there is no title in the post. I tried to use following code but is removed h1 and other tag. Please help.

```
<?php if (the_title() != '') { ?>
              <h1 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
              <?php } else { } ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get_the_title()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)). `the_title()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)) doesn't actually *return* anything but *prints* the title.

Comment: I used the following code to get my desired output.

  <?php if (get_the_title() != '') { ?>
                  <h1 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                  <?php } else { } ?>
Thank you Stephen, your idea worked

Comment: @user2339174 - would you mind accepting the answer so that's clear others / taken off the 'unanswered' pile?

Comment: Well sure :) :) :)